# How to trick a domain user's profile into not rebuilding when PC joined to (technically) different domain?

Tags: windows-domain

Our only DC (SBS 2003) failed recently and had to be rebuilt from scratch.

All user accounts have been recreated with identical names and passwords.

The name of the rebuilt DC is identical, as is the name of the domain (although, the new domain obviously now has a different SID, so this is now technically a completely different domain).

Workstations are being removed from the old domain and added to the new one, to establish valid trust relationships.

Is there anything I can do to prevent users starting off with blank profiles?

There is a lot of customization (desktop backgrounds, user settings, Outlook profiles etc.) which I would hate to discard if there is anything we can do to get the old profiles to connect to the new domain.

I was thinking of some sort of creative solution perhaps involving removing the profile registry key on a workstation (but leaving profile files and folders intact); however, when I tried this with a test account, the domain user's old profile on a PC was ignored, and a new profile was created the first time they logged in after joining the new domain.

What is the best course of action, given I am trying to minimize user disruption?

Comment: In the end, we had to do something fast and couldn't afford to wait long for the perfect solution, so have just rejoined the PCS to the new domain and reconfigured the user profiles again manually. I would still love to hear any ideas people have.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer given here would work: 
[How to change profile folder name without rebuilding user profile from scratch?](https://superuser.com/a/914999/645852)

That answer would suggest that you change the user's SID in the registry to reflect the SID in the new domain.